# convert ATL::CComBSTR to BSTR*

Tags: c#, c++, bstr

I am very new with C++. I created my C# DLL. I created Managed C++ DLL and reference it in my C# project. I want to return from C# dll a string value in a `char*` Problem is, I can't convert `CComBSTR` to `BSTR` ?

```
UINT    CHandler::GetData( UINT idx, char* lName) 
{
    HRESULT hRes= m_p->GetData(idx, CComBSTR(lName));
}
```

---

```
Error:  Fehler by CComBSTR(lNmae):  977 IntelliSense: It is no possible conversion of ""ATL::CComBSTR"" in ""BSTR *"" available.
```

My C# function has second Parameter with type `BSTR*`

Comment: What GetData function is you member variable calling?

Comment: That is my function from C#  `GetData(int idx, BSTR * lName)`

Comment: @Brita I understand your question, see my answer below.

Comment: It wants a pointer to a BSTR.  So you simply need to create one, use m_p->GetData(idx, &CComBSTR(lName)).  Note the & operator.  The BSTR is destroyed again after GetData() returns.

Comment: Tanks you so much user1, your Answer help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this...

**CHandler::GetData calling COM interface to fetch char* lName**

See how allocated memory is freed.

```
UINT CHandler::GetData(UINT idx, char* lName) 
{
    BSTR bstrName;
    HRESULT hRes= m_p->GetData(&bstrName);

    char *p= _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(bstrName);
    strcpy(lName,p);   //lName needs to be large enough to hold the string pointed to by p  
    delete[] p; //ConvertBSTRToString allocates a new string you will need to free

    //free the memory for the string
    ::SysFreeString(bstrName);
}
```

---

**COM interface method definition**

*Language: C++, please translate it to C#*
*Basically, you need to allocate BSTR inside c# method.*

See how memory is allocated and returned by COM method

```
HRESULT CComClass::GetData(long idx, BSTR* pbstr)
{
   try
   {
      //Let's say that m_str is CString
      *pbstr = m_str.AllocSysString();
      //...
   }
   catch (...)
   {
      return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
   }

   // The client is now responsible for freeing pbstr.
   return(S_OK);
}
```